# PDF generated by iText -> text missing after saving PDF to local drive

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am producing a PDF file in a HttpServlet with itText. Adding a Text on the canvas. If I open the url the PDF is shown correctly with the text. Also if I print it direclty from the browser, the text is visible on the printed paper. If I download the PDF on the other hand, the text not shown anymore (The image still is). The PDF can be viewed here: http://www.vegantastic.de/pdfTest

My code looks like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
// step 2
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
// step 3
document.open();

Font helvetica = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
BaseFont bf_helv = helvetica.getCalculatedBaseFont(false);
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
canvas.setFontAndSize(bf_helv, 12);

canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Test TEXT - Why is it missing after download?", 100, 800,0);

document.close();

// setting some response headers
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
        "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
// setting the content type
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
// the contentlength
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
// write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Is there any reasonable explanation for that or this this some kind of bug? Any way to resove this?

Comment: i think the problem exists only while opening it from `Acrobat Reader` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't adding the text correctly. The PDF you are creating contains a serious syntax error. Some PDF viewers will ignore this syntax error and show the text anyway (which may be why you can print the PDF from a browser); others will not show anything because you are showing text *outside* a text object.

There are different ways to add text at an absolute position. One way is to create a text object yourself:

```
canvas.beginText();
canvas.setFontAndSize(bf_helv, 12);
canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Test TEXT - Why is it missing after download?", 100, 800,0);
canvas.endText();
```

In this case, you need to manually *begin* and *end* the text object. That's missing in your code.

Another way, is to have iText create the text object:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
    new Phrase("Test TEXT - Why is it missing after download?", new Font(bf_helv, 12)),
    100, 800,0);
```

This single line is the equivalent of the four lines above.

**Important note:**

You are using this `canvas`:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
```

However: if your document contains opaque elements (an image, a colored rectangle,...), then whatever text you're adding will be covered by these opaque elements. Are you sure you don't want:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
canvas.saveState();
canvas.beginText();

canvas.setFontAndSize(bf_helv, 12);

canvas.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, "Test TEXT - Why is it missing after download?", 100, 800,0);

canvas.endText();
canvas.restoreState();
```